# How can you align all the cells to the left with css

Tags: html, css

I want to align all the cells with css to the left..

```
  #mainTopicTable td
{

  padding:20px; 
}
```

I want to add there some property that would align the cell to the left, but dont know which

Comment: What do you mean by aligning the cells to the left?

Comment: The content of `<td>` elements is aligned to the left by default.

Comment: yup..but I made a div..and aligned center..the table was in the div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<td>` element's content is left aligned by default. But if by any reason you can't see this then you can try with the following CSS.

```
#mainTopicTable td
{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[text-align: left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)